# After config nginx reverse proxy web page is not load

Tags: java, nginx, wildfly

To upload my web app to my vps host server I did the following steps:
1 - deploy the war file
2 - install nginx to reverse proxy
3 - configure nginx.conf

```
server {
              listen       80;
              listen       [::]:80;
              server_name  itcmedbr.com;
              #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
     
              # Load configuration files for the default server block.
              include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
     
              location / {
                  proxy_pass http://ipaddress;
     
              }
     
              error_page 404 /404.html;
                  location = /40x.html {
              }
     
              error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                  location = /50x.html {
              }
          }
```

4 - configure wildfly launch.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
      
       if [ "x$WILDFLY_HOME" = "x" ]; then
           WILDFLY_HOME="/opt/wildfly"
       fi
      
       if [[ "$1" == "domain" ]]; then
           $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/domain.sh -c $2 -b $3
       else
          $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -c $2 -b $3 -bmanagement=ipaddress
      fi
```

If I write http://ipaddress:80 or http://ipaddress:8080 the index page of my webapp is loaded but if I write [www.itcmedbr.com](http://www.itcmedbr.com) nothing is loaded and I receive "Unable to access this website".
Someone to help me?

Comment: What if you make the `server_name` include the www, i.e. `server_name  www.itcmedbr.com;`

Comment: Have you confit the DNS for you hostname?

Comment: Thanks stdumbar, yes I've configured dns of itcmedbr.com in my vps host server dns zone.
Hi LF-DevJourney,  server_name  defined as www.itcmedbr.com occur same problem i.e my webapp don't load.
Question: I've defined dns name as itcmedbr.com, what is the correct way?

Comment: In dns zone when you define the name of your domain in the cname field the www is defaulted.

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy pass needs to also list the port number wildfly is listening on, most likely port 8080

Comment: Hi Will, for this: proxy_pass http://ipaddress:8080; problem still the same.

Comment: So you have changed server_name to have www.itcmedbr.com ?     What is the exact error when you try and access? What do you see on the web page and in the nginx logs?

Comment: yes server_name is set as www.itcmedbr.com, the error is that my web page is not loaded and I receive that is not possible to access this site. I don't have nginx log.

Comment: Yes I changed server_name to have www.itcmedbr.com. The error is that my web page is not loaded I receive "Is not possible to access this site". I don't have nginx log.

Comment: The error should give a reason, like connection refused, timed out, 500 errors etc